# How can I get this custom function to work with lapply?

Tags: r, list, function, lapply

I'm trying to do a scale of effect analysis that uses the custom function found here: https://github.com/phuais/multifit/blob/master/multifit.R

It works fine for every list element of SAND_lc_list when I run each element separately, with no errors or warnings.

```
test <- multifit(mod = "glm", 
                    multief = buffer_names,     #column names
                    formula = presence ~ multief,
                    args = c("family = binomial"),
                    data = as.data.frame(SAND_lc_list[[9]]),      #which landcover variable
                    criterion = "AIC",
                    plot_est = T,
                    site_id = "Plot",
                    print_sum = TRUE)

The model including the effect 'r7500' was the best model according to the specified criterion (AIC, which.min)

Call:
glm(formula = presence ~ r7500, family = binomial, data = as.data.frame(SAND_lc_list[[9]]))

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-0.8244  -0.1537  -0.1160  -0.1051   3.1663  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value        Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -5.3623     0.7944  -6.750 0.0000000000148 ***
r7500         8.2955     2.5777   3.218         0.00129 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 59.491  on 316  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 49.625  on 315  degrees of freedom
AIC: 53.625

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 7
```

However, when I try to use lapply to apply the function to each element of the list, I get the following error.

```
SAND_models <- lapply(SAND_lc_list, function(x) multifit(mod = "glm", 
                                                         multief = buffer_names,     #column names
                                                         formula = presence ~ multief,
                                                         args = c("family = binomial"),
                                                         data = as.data.frame(x),     
                                                         criterion = "AIC",
                                                         plot_est = T,
                                                         site_id = "Plot",
                                                         print_sum = TRUE))

Warning messages:
1: Fatal errors were found in all the models. Check them out by typing $Models to the generated object

> SAND_models$barren$models
$r200
<simpleError in h(simpleError(msg, call)): error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.data.frame': object 'x' not found>
```

I'm guessing I don't understand something about how lapply handles x - I never know if it is passing SAND_lc_list[i] or SAND_lc_list[[i]] to the function. I also wonder if it could have something to do with how the custom function is structured.

Any thoughts on how I could get this work?

Comment: I am pretty sure this is happening because the [source](https://github.com/phuais/multifit/blob/master/multifit.R#L250) has the line `expression <- paste(mod, "(data =", deparse(substitute(data)), args, ")")`, which is dangerous and can have weird side effects in anonymous functions. Worth trying a loop.

Comment: I've been trying it and having a different set of weird issues there too. See comment to the answer posted by @akrun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the foreach is not working, then loop over the sequence and extract the object

```
lapply(seq_along(SAND_lc_list), function(i) {
      tmp <- as.data.frame(SAND_lc_list[[i]])
      multifit(mod = "glm", 
                    multief = buffer_names,     #column names
                    formula = presence ~ multief,
                    args = c("family = binomial"),
                    data = tmp,    
                    criterion = "AIC",
                    plot_est = TRUE,
                    site_id = "Plot",
                    print_sum = TRUE)})
```

If the object is using substitute, it can be an issue

```
out_lst <- vector('list', length(SAND_lc_list))
for(i in seq_along(SAND_lc_list)) {
    expr <- sprintf('multifit(mod = "glm", 
                    multief = buffer_names,     #column names
                    formula = presence ~ multief,
                    args = c("family = binomial"),
                    data = as.data.frame(SAND_lc_list[[%d]]),    
                    criterion = "AIC",
                    plot_est = TRUE,
                    site_id = "Plot",
                    print_sum = TRUE)', i)
    out_lst[[i]] <- eval(parse(text = expr))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this has got me part of the way there. With this version, I'm no longer getting the fatal error described above, but nor is it working properly. Both with this code, and when I try using a for loop on the multifit function, many of the models it produces have errors that do not occur when the function isn't used in a loop.

Comment: @canderson156 when you say not working properly, is it from the `for` loop version or `lapply`

Comment: Both. Same issue actually

Comment: In trying to troubleshoot, I've found that having as.data.frame(SAND_lc_list[[i]]) with i = 1 in the function produces errors, but, I've found that as.data.frame(SAND_lc_list[[1]]) works fine. Even though when saved as their own objects they are identical

Comment: @canderson156 perhaps, the function is looking for the object in the global env and if that object is not found, it shows the error?.  I didn't test it as there was no reproducible example

Comment: Seems like a good guess. I'll see if I can figure out a reproducible example.

Comment: @canderson156 I think, if we construct an expressions and then `eval/parse`, it should work.  Please see my update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243585/discussion-between-canderson156-and-akrun).

Comment: What does the '%d' in 'data = as.data.frame(SAND_lc_list[[%d]])' do?

Comment: @canderson156 that is to interpolate the numeric `i` in `sprintf`